# Необходимо передать данные из одного дочернего компонента в другой. ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

Недавно изучаю ReactJS и столкнулся с проблемой, необходимо взять данные из одного функционального компонента и передать в другой. Полагаю, что необходимо использовать родительский компонент, как посредника, но не уверен каким образом. Прошу подсказать как реализовать это с помощью пропсов. Возможно проще сделать через Redux, но в данном случае необходимо через пропсы.

Родительский компонент:

```
const Page: React.FC = () => {
 return (<div>
  <Part1 />
  <Part2 />
 </div>)
}
```

Соответственно необходимо передать из Part1 в Part2 массив.

Part1:

```
 const Part1: React.FC = () => {
     return (<div>
      smf
     </div>)
    }
```

Part2:

```
 const Part2: React.FC = () => {
     return (<div>
      smf
     </div>)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример, как это делается через пропсы

```
const Page = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(0)
  return (<div>
   <Part1 value={id} />
   <Part2 click={setId} />
  </div>)
 }

 const Part1 = (props) => {
  return (<div>
   {props.value}
  </div>)
 }

const Part2 = (props) => {
  return (<div>
   <button onClick={() => props.click(i => ++i)}>UP</button>
  </div>)
 }
```

Создается состояние у родительского компонента. В дочерние компоненты пропсами передаются значения состояния.

В первый само значение, во второй фукнцию, которая меняет состояние в родительском компоненте

Comment: Посмотреть, как работает, можно в [песочнице](https://codesandbox.io/s/statechange-d1emsh?file=/src/App.js) - внизу.

Comment: Спасибо, я то пытался функцию передавать...

Comment: @Kjan Можно и фукнцию отдельную передавать. Все зависит от необходимости в реализации того или иного. По сути, передача setId это передача фукнции )