# React вызов компонента1 из компонента2

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как из одного компонента вызвать другой?
В Component1 лежит кнопка, на которую мы нажимаем и что-нибудь (например ререндер компонента) происходит с Component2.
Как это сделать, используя хуки?

Component1

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
 
const Component1 = () => {      
     function myFunc(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         // ?
     }
    
      return (
    <div>
             <Button onClick={() => { myFunc(); }} >
                 go!
             </Button>  
        </div>
      )
}

export { Component1 }
```

Component2

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
 
const Component2 = () => {  
            
    // ---------------force rerender--------------------
    const [_, forceUpdate] = useReducer((x) => x + 1, 0);   
    const reRender = () => {
        forceUpdate();
    };
            
      return (
    <div>
        Rerernder me!
    </div>
      )
}

export { Component2 }
```

App

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Component1} from "./Component1.jsx";
import {Component2} from "./Component2.jsx";

 
const App = () => { 
   return(
      <div>
           <div className="container">
               <h3 >hello gays</h3>
                   <div className="flex-row">
                        <div 
                           className="flex-large" >
                           <Component1 />
                       </div>
                       <div 
                           className="flex-large" >
                           <Component2 />
                       </div>                                         
                    </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));

export { App }
```

Comment: [Это ответ на ваш вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1496465/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-reactjs/1496473#1496473)