# Как отсортировать результат компонента React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, сортировка

Есть два компонента React. Первый (Filters) отвечает за сортировку и фильтрацию данных, второй (SearchResults) выводит на клиент данные json.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне импортировать результаты второго компонента в первый и в дальнейшем отсротировать эти результаты через sort().

Первый компонент:

```
import data from '../flights.json';
import SearchResults from './SearchResults';

export default function Filters() {
    const tickets = [];

    for (const ticket of data.result.flights) {
        tickets.push(ticket.flight);
    }

  return (
    <div style={{fontFamily: 'sans-serif'}}>
        <div className="sorting">
            <h4>Сортировать</h4>
            <div>
                <input onChange={() => {console.log(<SearchResults />);}} type="radio" name="sorting"/>- по возрастанию цены
            </div>
            <div>
                <input onChange={() => {console.log('sort by descending');}} type="radio" name="sorting"/>- по убыванию цены
            </div>
            <div>
                <input onChange={() => {console.log('sort by time (from low to high)');}} type="radio" name="sorting"/>- по времени в пути
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="filtering">
            <h4>Фильтровать</h4>
            <div><input type="checkbox" name="transfer"/>- 1 пересадка</div>
            <div><input type="checkbox" name="without transfer"/>- без пересадок</div>
        </div>
        <div className="price">
            <h4>Цена</h4>
            <div style={{marginBottom: 15}}>От <input type="text" value=""/></div>
            <div>До <input type="text" value=""/></div>
        </div>
        <div className="companies">
            <h4>Авиакомпании</h4>
            <div style={{fontSize: 14}}>
                <input type="checkbox" name="company name"/>- {tickets[0].carrier.caption} от {tickets[0].price.total.amount} руб.<br />
                <input type="checkbox" name="company name"/>- {tickets[1].carrier.caption} от {tickets[1].price.total.amount} руб.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
<input onChange={() => {Results should be sorted by price ascending}} type="radio" name="sorting"/>- по возрастанию цены
```

Второй компонент(результаты которого нужно сортировать с помощью первого компонента):

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import data from '../flights.json';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';

export default function SearchResults() {
    const tickets = [];

    for (const ticket of data.result.flights) {
        tickets.push(ticket.flight);
    }

    const [ticketsNum, setTicketsNum] = useState(2);

    return (
        tickets.slice(0, ticketsNum).map((item, index) => {
            return <div className='results' style={{marginBottom: 25, fontFamily: 'sans-serif'}}>
                {
                    item.legs.map((leg, index) => {
                        const durationHours = Math.floor(leg.duration / 60);
                        const durationMinutes = leg.duration % 60;
                        const durationTime = durationHours + ' ч ' + durationMinutes + ' мин';
                        const firstSegment = leg.segments[0];
                        const lastSegment = leg.segments[leg.segments.length - 1];
                        const departureCity = firstSegment.departureCity || firstSegment.departureAirport;
                        const arrivalCity = lastSegment.arrivalCity || lastSegment.arrivalAirport;
                        const departureTime = firstSegment.departureDate.indexOf("T");
                        const arrivalTime = lastSegment.arrivalDate.indexOf("T");
                        const airline = firstSegment.airline.caption;
                        const transfer = leg.segments.length - 1;
                        const departureDayMonth = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru', {day: "numeric", month: "short"}).format(new Date(firstSegment.departureDate));
                        const departureWeekDay = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru', {weekday: "short"}).format(new Date(firstSegment.departureDate));
                        const arrivalDayMonth = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru', {day: "numeric", month: "short"}).format(new Date(lastSegment.arrivalDate));
                        const arrivalWeekDay = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('ru', {weekday: "short"}).format(new Date(lastSegment.arrivalDate));
                        return (
                            <div className="route">
                                {index === 0 ?
                                <div className="companyAndPrice" style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "space-between", paddingInline: 15, backgroundColor: "rgb(12 131 190)", color: "white", height: 50, fontFamily: 'sans-serif'}}>
                                    <span style={{paddingTop: 10}}>{item.carrier.caption}</span>
                                    <div className="price" style={{textAlign: 'right', paddingTop: 5}}>
                                        <span style={{fontSize: 25}}>{item.price.total.amount}&nbsp;&#8381;</span>
                                        <h6 style={{margin: 0, fontWeight: 100}}>Стоимость для одного взрослого пассажира</h6>
                                    </div>
                                </div> : null
                                }
                                <div style={{borderBottom: '1px solid lightgrey', padding: 10}} className="routeName"> 
                                    {departureCity.caption}, 
                                    &nbsp;{firstSegment.departureAirport.caption}
                                    &nbsp;<span style={{color: 'rgb(12 131 190)'}}>({firstSegment.departureAirport.uid}) &#8594;</span>
                                    &nbsp;{arrivalCity.caption},
                                    &nbsp;{lastSegment.arrivalAirport.caption}
                                    &nbsp;<span style={{color: 'rgb(12 131 190)'}}>({lastSegment.arrivalAirport.uid})</span>
                                </div>
                                <div className='travelTime' style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between', padding: "12px 12px 0 12px", alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                    <div style={{fontSize: "20px"}}>{firstSegment.departureDate.substr(departureTime + 1, 5)}&nbsp;<span style={{color: "rgb(12 131 190)", fontSize: "15px"}}>{departureDayMonth}&nbsp;{departureWeekDay}</span></div>
                                    {durationTime}
                                    <div style={{fontSize: "20px"}}><span style={{color: "rgb(12 131 190)", fontSize: "15px"}}>{arrivalDayMonth}&nbsp;{arrivalWeekDay}</span>&nbsp;{lastSegment.arrivalDate.substr(arrivalTime + 1, 5)}</div>
                                </div>
                                {transfer > 0 ? 
                                    <Divider style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', width: 500, marginLeft: 50}}>
                                        <span style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', paddingBottom: 5, color: 'orange'}}>
                                            {transfer + " пересадка"}
                                        </span>
                                    </Divider> : 
                                    <Divider style={{padding: 5, marginBottom: 10, display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', width: 500, marginLeft: 50}}></Divider>
                                }
                                <div className="companyName" style={{padding: "10px 0 0 10px"}}>
                                    Рейс выполняет: {index === 0 ? airline : 
                                    firstSegment.hasOwnProperty('operatingAirline') == true ? firstSegment.operatingAirline.caption : 
                                        airline}
                                </div>
                                {index === 0 ? <hr style={{backgroundColor: "dodgerblue", border: "1px solid dodgerblue"}}/> : <button onClick={() => {alert("Well, ticket has been selected")}} onMouseOver={event => {event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#d28800"}} onMouseLeave={event => {event.target.style.backgroundColor = "orange"}}  style={{border: 0, color: "white", backgroundColor: "orange", width: "100%", height: 35, marginTop: 5}}>ВЫБРАТЬ</button>}
                                                             
                            </div>
                        )
                   })
                }
                {index === ticketsNum - 1 ? 
                    <div style={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 10}}>
                        <button onClick={() => setTicketsNum(ticketsNum + 2)} style={{width: 200, height: 30, fontSize: 17}}>Показать еще</button>
                    </div> : null
                }
            </div>
        }
        )
    )
}
```

[image: Слева первый компонент, сс помощью которого должна осуществлять сортировка результатов второго компонента(справа)]

Comment: Покажите эти компоненты и как они связаны друг с другом

Comment: @SwaD Отредактировал вопрос, полностью включив оба компонента

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что в коде, первый компонени не является родителем второго и стоят они рядом в каком то общем компоненте родителя?

Comment: @SwaD, верно. Компоненты в этом плане не зависят друг от друга и не являются родителем или дочерним элементами.

Comment: Вам надо вынести состояние в общий компонент и его передавать.  Сейчас ваши компоненты никак не будут реагировать на изменение данных. [Как передавать данные от одного дочернего компонента другому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1496465/)

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть общее состояние `tickets` для обоих компонентов.

Возможные решения:

1. Использовать библиотеки для управления состоянием - `redux`, `zustand`.
2. Если это pet-проект, можно использовать компонент-контейнер с `useState`.